# Javascript code issue in Head of HTML page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

In Asp.net MVC website, due to some reason I access Google Analytics tracking code from MSSQL database. When it is rendered in head tag of the html page, it has alphanumeric characters in some places, i.e. it replaces "," with "`&#39;`", like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[&#39;GoogleAnalyticsObject&#39;] ....
...
...
</script>
```

Actually, I get messages from Google analytics that code is not accessed in my website. Its seems that Google has some issues reading this type of code. Not Sure!

Any help please!

Comment: `&#39;` is `'`, not `,`. Basically your quotes are encoded as HTML entities and are invalid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Razor templating, try wrapping the output in your view with:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.TrackingCode)
```

ASP.NET MVC will escape characters automatically for you, you just need to unescape them.